# Text to speech using ispeech in python

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, python-2.7

I want to convert text to speech in my project. i tried with ispeech (www.ispeech.org) api. can anyone explain an example of ispeech using javascript,jquery or python.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: @mjk hello mj.. I have try this code (<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x5L57Ef3olRieAT393-ymDndNe51TXAnmnY5kUafGjk/edit?usp=sharing>). I am getting : Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Comment: @mjk I also tried with script. Here is link(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JXaNa_ZUAL-N_iGcxF9g381wfESzsdTJvNtEgpMt7E4/edit?usp=sharing). This code works fine in chrome, but while in mozilla and IE its not working.

Comment: @mjk i also tried this using python packages. For, that i installed pyttsx, it works ok in simple desktop application. Would this useful in web app? and sound quality of this package is not good. Give me suggestions, if you have any idea about this. Thanks in advance. Waiting for you reply..

Answer (score 0):

example using jquery

```
a = '<data>'
a +=    '<apikey>developerdemokeydeveloperdemokey</apikey>'
a +=    '<action>convert</action>'
a +=    '<text>hello world</text>'
a +=    '<voice>usenglishfemale</voice>'
a +='</data>';
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://api.ispeech.org",
  type: "POST",
  data : {xml : a},
  contentType: "xml"
 });
```

Comment: this is not helpfull to me because, this code is not handling response. I want to bind this response with audio tag or script. here, i have tried below codes. please go through link. 1) It is giving stack size exceed error in chrome(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x5L57Ef3olRieAT393-ymDndNe51TXAnmnY5kUafGjk/edit?usp=sharing).  2) and if i am trying using script, it is not useful in mozilla and IE. Here is second example link(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JXaNa_ZUAL-N_iGcxF9g381wfESzsdTJvNtEgpMt7E4/edit?usp=sharing).. Pls give me efficient solution, if possible. Thanks in advance..